# TypeScript decorator not working on derived class

Tags: typescript, decorator

### Problem

I'm working on a project where I want to make a decorator for a class, but I get this error:

```
Type 'typeof Controller' is not assignable to type 'typeof MainController'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

---

### My Code

Here is the code I've written:

#### File 1

```
export function myDecorator(arg: string) {
    return (cls: typeof Base) => {
        // more code
        return cls;
    };
}
export function otherDecorator(arg: string) {
    return (cls: Base, ...) => {
        // more code
    };
}
export abstract class Base {
    // some methods
}
```

#### File 2

```
import { myDecorator, otherDecorator, Base } from "./file1";
@myDecorator("some text") // here I get the error
class Derived extends Base {
    @otherDecorator("other text") // everything is fine here
    public myMethod() {}
}
```

What could be my problem? Because normally it should be possible to do something. Or do you have another suggestion for me? I just want to restrict the `myDecorator` to any class derived from `Base`

---

**Edit:** I solved the problem. Look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: I changed the signature of the `myDecorator` return function:

```
return <T extends Controller>(cls: Constructor<T>): Constructor<T> => {}
```

`Constructor<T>` is just a type like this:

```
export type Constructor<Class, Args extends any[] = any[]> = new (...args: Args) => Class;
```

It works now.